# Gráfico con movimiento aspx

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

Necesito hacer algo similar a esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En `C#` ya sea con `Telerik`, `JQuery` o cualquier otra cosa que me sirva para hacerlo.

El problema es que no tengo la más mínima idea de como hacerlo, he buscado por internet y no logro encontrar algo, así que si alguien sabe de alguna página, código o algo que me pueda ayudar a realizarlo, se los agradecería mucho.

Comment: ¿Necesitas mostrar porcentaje en el loading? Si no es así, evítalo y utiliza un gif o una fuenta llamada font-awesome (es gratuita) ¿Necesitas consultar procesos del backend para actualizar el loading? (De ser así, te recomiendo utilizar un webmethod, JQuery y AJAX) Si necesitas apoyo con la lógica, coméntamelo. Saludos.

Comment: Sí, necesito mostrar el porcentaje en el loading. Si fuera el gif, cómo o dónde puedo crearlo? Con el font-awesome no tengo idea de cómo poder hacer eso. Y sí necesito consuiltar procesos en el backend porque el porcentaje proviene del resultado de un store procedure, entonces si tuvieras más detalle te lo agradezco.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para la parte gráfica en cliente, aquí tienes una explicación perfecta realizada con Bootstrap:

[Respuesta StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10007212/twitter-bootstrap-progress-bar-animation-on-page-load)

Y el ejemplo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5w5ku/1/)

Answer (score 0):

No se puede, es imposible, por favor no te rompas la cabeza con el progreso de un store procedure. Yo alguna vez en mi vida me topé con eso, y utilizaba transacciones, y esto no me daba visibilidad del progreso, por lo tanto es imposible conectarlo con el backend. Te recomiendo utilizar el font-awesome pero no muestres progreso, porque acabarás por no entregar nada. Te sugiero dejarlo como un pendiente y entregar algo funcional, de lo contrario vas a malgastar tu tiempo.

Te dejo un enlace para que veas cómo funciona el font-awesome y otro para que veas cómo funciona AJAX con JQuery y métodos web.

[Calling ASP.Net WebMethod using jQuery AJAX](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Calling-ASPNet-WebMethod-using-jQuery-AJAX.aspx)

fontawesome . io/ examples/

Para hacer uso de font-awesome, tienes que hacer referencia en tus html

Si no sabes nada de front-end, te daré un tip: la ruta en href, es dónde se ubica tu archivofont-awesome.min.css en tu proyecto.

Espero que te sirva.

Comment: Tienes razón, no logré hacer lo que deseaba, por lo tanto utilicé un control de `Telerik` para simular algo parecido. Gracias por la ayuda.